# Convert nested JSON Arrays to Chart.js input

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, chart.js2

I can't seem to arrange my data correctly for React-Chart.js I currently have my data in all in one array:

```
[[Array(9)], [Array(9)],[Array(9)], [Array(9)]]
```

Edit: each of the 4 arrays have 9 [key, value] pairs in their own array:

```
 (9) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
 (9) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
 (9) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
 (9) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
```

In the future I would like to be able to add more arrays.

I would like to use each array as it's own series with a name from another source:

```
 {
    label: props.name[0],
    data: [
      aminos[0][0],
      aminos[0][1],
      aminos[0][2],
      aminos[0][3],
      aminos[0][4],
      aminos[0][5],
      aminos[0][6]
      etc...
    ]
 },
 {
    label: props.name[1],
    data: [
      aminos[1][0],
      aminos[1][1],
      aminos[1][2],
      aminos[1][3],
      aminos[1][4],
      aminos[1][5],
      aminos[1][6],
      etc...
    ]
 },
...
```

Hope that makes sense, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below snippet should be helpful, I'm not sure about the structure of your source array, hence have generalised this

```js
//sample data
var recArray = [ 
  [ 
    [ 'key1','value1.1'], 
    ['key2','value2.1'],
    ['key9','value9.1']
  ],
  [ 
    [ 'key1','value1.2'], 
    ['key2','value2.2'],
    ['key9','value9.2']
  ]
];

//result object
lblGroupedRecords = {}

//flattens the nested array
//choose nested level based on your level of nesting
flattenedRecords = recArray.flat(2);

var handle=0;
while(handle<flattenedRecords.length) {
  var key = flattenedRecords[handle++];
  var value = flattenedRecords[handle++];
  (lblGroupedRecords[key] = lblGroupedRecords[key] || []).push(value);
}

console.log(lblGroupedRecords)
```

Comment: This didn't quite work, it was definitely my fault though I forgot to mention the nested arrays(2) in the 4 different arrays.  I edited the post now to correct this.

Comment: Do you mean something like this :    ```[
 [
   [
     ['key1'],['value1'], ['key2'],['value2'], ['key3'],['value3'], ... ['key9'],['value9']]

  ]
  ...
]```

Comment: Not quite its like this [ [key, value], [key, value], [key, value], ...]

Comment: Updated the code, choose nested array level as the argument for flat appropriately